# Scaling only some columns of a training set and a test set

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I often have to deal with the following issue:

- I have a test set and a training set
- I want to scale all columns of a training set, *except* for a few ones which are identified by a character vector
- then, based on the sample means and sample standard deviations of the selected columns of the training set, I want to rescale the test set too

Currently, my workflow is kludgy: I use an index vector and then partial assignment to scale only some columns of the train set. I store the means and standard deviations from the scaling operation on the training set, and I use them to scale the test set. I was wondering if there could be a simpler way, without having to install `caret` (for a series of reasons, I'm not a big fan of `caret` and I definitely won't start using it just for this problem).
Here is my current workflow:

```
# define dummy train and test sets
train <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:10], months = month.abb[1:10], numbers = 1:10,
                    x = rnorm(10, 1), y = runif(10))
test <- train
test$x <- rnorm(10, 1)
test$y <- runif(10)

# names of variables I don't want to scale
varnames <- c("letters", "months", "numbers")

# index vector of columns which must not be scaled
index <- names(train) %in% varnames

# scale only the columns not in index
temp <- scale(train[, !index])
train[, !index] <- temp

# get the means and standard deviations from temp, to scale test too
means <- attr(temp, "scaled:center")
standard_deviations <- attr(temp, "scaled:center")

# scale test
test[, !index] <- scale(test[, !index], center = means, scale = standard_deviations)
```

Is there a simpler/more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I recommend combining your train and test data set into a single data.frame. Then scale only numeric columns using `if(is.numeric)` or something like that.

Comment: Depending on the application, I would disagree with the above comment from CPak. If your goal is to develop a predictive model, then you absolutely must scale training and testing data separately. Combining the datasets will "leak" information from test data into the scale factor calculations.

Comment: @kgolayev I agree with you, I was thinking exactly of the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice question and I have tried a lot to come up with an answer.
I think this is a bit more elegant code:

```
    train0=train%>%select(-c(letters, months, numbers))%>%as.matrix%>%scale
means <- attr(train0, "scaled:center")
standard_deviations <- attr(train0, "scaled:center")
train0=cbind(select(train,c(letters, months, numbers)),train0)
test0=test%>%select(-c(letters, months, numbers))%>%as.matrix%>%scale(center = means, scale = standard_deviations)
test0=cbind(select(test,c(letters, months, numbers)),test0)
```

I have tried hard to work with `mutate_at` in order to avoid `cbind` extra code but with no lack